# How do I create a video thumbnail

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, video

Can I create an active, small but uncropped video window, whilst working on a different window

Comment: Which video application are you using?

Answer (score 1):

#### QuickTime Player

Open the video in QuickTime Player, resize the player, then select View → Float on Top.
QuickTime Player hides all of the UI when you move your mouse outside of the window.

Answer (score 1):

#### VLC

Open the video in VLC, resize the player, then select Video → Float on Top.
There is considerably more UI shown on the VLC player than the QuickTime player though.